# Material UI Datagrid link column stop onRowClicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am using a Material UI Datagrid to display some data.
One of the columns displays a link that opens an url in another tab.
On row clicked I want to navigate to another page, but I do not want to this when the link is clicked.

I am able to simply disable click behaviour on the whole cell of the link, but that is not completely desired. Do you know a solution where I can somehow stop the `onRowClicked` from being executed from within the `onClick` of the Link for example?

A simplified example of what I am using:

```
<DataGrid 
    columns={[
        { flex: 200, field: 'name', headerName: 'Naam' },
        {
            flex: 250,
            field: 'url',
            headerName: 'Link',
            renderCell: (cell: GridCellParams) => (
                <Box width="100%" overflow="scroll">
                    <Link
                        href={cell.value}
                        target="_blank"
                    >
                        Click here
                    </Link>
                </Box>
            ),
        },
    ]}
    onRowClicked={(row) => {
        navigate(Routes.OTHER_PAGE.replace(':id', row.id))
    }}
    rows={rows}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}` to the Link solves it.